# jQuery validation check single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate an element with jQuery validation. How should I do that? My element conditions are: its length is more than 5 and it is a required field.

My element code:

```
<input type="password" name="password_field" />
```

I don't expect `$('form).validation()` method. I want to validate that method without having form selector.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `.validation()` method in this plugin and you cannot avoid using `$('form').validate()`... it's the only way to initialize the plugin.  Please include enough relevant code to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with the code within your jsFiddle...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $('textarea').validate({
            ....
```

1. The `.validate()` method would NEVER go inside of a `click` handler.  The `.validate()` method is the initialization method of the plugin and only belongs in the DOM ready event handler.
2. You cannot attach the `.validate()` method to the `textarea` element.  As explained in item #1, it is the initialization method of the plugin and only gets attached to the `form` element.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       $('form').validate({ // initialize plugin on your form
           ....
   ```
3. Your `button` element must contain a `type="submit"` attribute in order for validation to work properly.

   ```
   <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
   ```

**Working DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/e639w4c3/**

**I suggest that you take the time to review [the official documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and the basic usage guidelines on [the Tag Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).**

---

> Title:  jQuery validation check single element

To check a single element, you can attach [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) directly to your field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').validate({ // initialize plugin on your form
        // your options
    }); 

    $('#myElement').valid(); // <- validate a single element

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get why you don't want to have the form selector. The solution to your problem would be straight forward

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    password_field: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    }
  },
  messages: {
    name: {
      required: "This field is required",
      minlength: "Password should at least have 5 characters"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you then please copy your html code so we can help you better? Or at least say what doesn't work